# in Magento controller, can't get session variable which was set before redirect on this action

Tags: session, magento-1.9

in rewrited customer controller is set:

```
if(!empty($customer_data)){

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    // or $session = $this->_getSession();
    $session->setEmail($email);
    // or  $email   = $session->setData('email', $email);
    Mage::getSingleton(‘core/session’)->setMySessionVariable($email); 
    $this->_redirectSuccess($this->_getUrl('*/*/customerChoice/'));

    ...

    }
```

then, on other customer ontroller's action, in which i redirect from the code above, i do:

```
public function customerChoiceAction()
{
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    // or $session = $this->_getSession();

    $email   = $session->getEmail();
    // or  $email   = $session->getData('email');
```

but i get null in result, where to dig and hove to solve? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue in CHROME only, in Firefox, everything works fine.